# Передача значения из дочернего элемента в родительский React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Есть код

```
let token1234 = null

const HomeStackScreen = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {
      token1234 == null ? (
        <Stack.Screen name='Full' update component={Full} options={{ headerShown: false, headerStyle: { elevation: 0 }, animationEnabled: false }} />
      )
      :
       (
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerTitle: 'Chats', headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 25 }, headerStyle: { elevation: 0 }, headerShown: false }} />

      )
    }
  </Stack.Navigator>
)
```

Как правильно написать код на странице Full, чтобы при клике там на кнопку, token1234 изменился на значение и последующие разы отображалась страница Home

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const updateToken = value => {
    setToken(value)
  }
  
  if (token) {
    return  <Stack.Screen name='Home' updateToken={updateToken} />
  } else {
    return  <Stack.Screen name='Full' updateToken={updateToken} />
  }
}
```

Затем в компоненте `Stack.Screen` вы получите пропс `updateToken`, который я передал выше и по клику на кнопку передатите туда значение токена.
У компонента `HomeScreen` обновится состояние, это вызовет его перерендер. А так как `token` уже будет, то он отрендерит вам вариант из `else`

Comment: А можно вопрос, как именно лучше записать событие onPress в дочернем элементе с передачей токена? (и я почему-то не могу найти его состояние в дочернем элементе при обращении через props, пишет - undefined)

Comment: потому что вам нужно тогда его передать снаружи `<Stack.Screen name='Home' updateToken={updateToken}  token={token} />` если в рамках моего кода. В дочернем компоненте вы просто обрабатывается `onPress`. Напишите функцию обработчик для `onPress` и в нем уже запускайте `props.updateToken()`. Пример: `const handlePress = (event) => { props.updateToken(event.target.value) }` и в компоненте `<textarea onPress={handlePress} />`

Comment: Возможно в react-native это работает немного по-другому, но при вызове  `            onPress={() =>handlePress}` ничего не происходит и в косоли (ее поместил в функцию для проверки ) ничего не отображается. (Понятно, что оно ее не вызывает на-прямую, а только обрабатывает, но должно же вызываться хоть что-то)

Comment: @Miangel, к сожалению я не работал с `react-native`. Возможно, там действительно по-другому